# lighttpd proxy a directory to another server

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

in `/etc/lighttpd/vhosts`

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/sr/" {
    proxy.server = (
        "" => ( (
            "host" => "x.x.x.x",
            "port" => 80
        ) )
    )
}
```

mod_proxy - enabled
but nothing hapends, `example.com/sr/` forward to 404 page on first server

Answer (score -1):

Is your `$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/sr/" {` inside a `$HTTP["host"]` clause ?

Have you tried:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^sample.com)$" {
  proxy.server = (
      "/sr/" => ( (
          "host" => "x.x.x.x",
          "port" => 80
      ) )
  )
}
```